# How to demosaic a bayer RAW image?

Tags: android, demosaicing

I have a proprietary bayer RAW image which I need to demosaic on Android to display the image. I am reading the file header byte by byte to retrieve the resolution info (imageWidth/imageHeight). After the header there is the pixel data from byte 2000 and following.
How can I demosaic this bayer pixel data on Android to display the image?

Here is my code which reads the byte data and retreives the resolution:

```
File file = new File(path);
int size = (int) file.length();
byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
try {
    BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    buf.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

int x1 = bytes[1056];
int x2 = bytes[1057];
int x3 = bytes[1058];
int x4 = bytes[1059];
int imageWidth = (x1 << 24) + (x2 << 16) + (x3 << 8) + x4;

int y1 = bytes[1056];
int y2 = bytes[1057];
int y3 = bytes[1058];
int y4 = bytes[1059];
int imageHeigth = (y1 << 24) + (y2 << 16) + (y3 << 8) + y4;

// image data bytes[2000] and following, one pixel per byte
//
// bayer format:
//
// BGBGBGBG....
// GRGRGRGR....
// BGBGBGBG....
// ............
// ............
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can demosaic a bayer RAW image using a third party libaray [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/platforms/android/). 
It has a function `Imgproc.demosaicing()` that converts a raw Bayer image to desired format

You can lookup this cpp of OpenCV that can be used in android.

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/demosaicing.cpp

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Answering this question is kind of hard: There are alot of different debayer/demosaic algorithms. The latest are very complicated.

Your main problem is Android, which is based on Java. There are really no great libraries for debayering.

It highly depends on which algorithm you want to use. Here are some which you could implement in you application, based on the Imaging library [ImageJ](http://umanitoba.ca/faculties/science/astronomy/jwest/plugins.html):

```
public class Debayer_Image implements PlugInFilter {

ImagePlus imp;
ImageProcessor ip;
int width;
int height;
static boolean normalize = false;
static boolean equalize = false;
static boolean stackHist = false;
static boolean showColour = false;
static boolean median = false;
static boolean gauss = false;
static int med_radius = 2;
static int gauss_radius = 2;

public int setup(String arg, ImagePlus imp) {
    IJ.register(Debayer_Image.class);
    if (IJ.versionLessThan("1.32c"))
        return DONE;
    imp.unlock();   
    this.imp = imp;
    return DOES_16;
}

public void run(ImageProcessor ip) {
    width = imp.getWidth();
    height = imp.getHeight();
    ImageStack rgb = new ImageStack(width, height, imp.getProcessor().getColorModel());
    String[] orders = {"R-G-R-G", "B-G-B-G", "G-R-G-R", "G-B-G-B"};
    String[] algorithms = {"Replication", "Bilinear", "Smooth Hue", "Adaptive Smooth Hue"}; 

    int row_order = /*TODO SET YOUR ROW ORDER HERE*/
    int algorithm = /*TODO SET YOUR ALGORITHM HERE*/
    /* TODO SET VALUES FOR normalize, equalize, ... */

    options = "saturated=0.5";
    if (normalize) options = options + " normalize";
    if (equalize) options = options + " equalize";
    options = options + " normalize_all";
    if (stackHist) options = options + " use"; 

    /* TODO ONLY USE ONE CALL */
    rgb = replicate_decode(row_order) 
        = average_decode(row_order);
        = smooth_decode(row_order);
        = adaptive_decode(row_order);

    if (median) IJ.run("Median...", "radius="+med_radius+" stack");
    if (gauss) IJ.run("Median...", "radius="+gauss_radius+" stack");
    if (normalize || equalize) IJ.run("Enhance Contrast", options);

    if (showColour) IJ.run("Convert Stack to RGB");

}

ImageStack replicate_decode(int row_order) { //Replication algorithm
    ip = imp.getProcessor();
    width = imp.getWidth();
    height = imp.getHeight();
    int one = 0;
    ImageStack rgb = new ImageStack(width, height, imp.getProcessor().getColorModel());
    ImageProcessor r = new ShortProcessor(width,height);
    ImageProcessor g = new ShortProcessor(width,height);
    ImageProcessor b = new ShortProcessor(width,height);
    //Short[] pixels = ip.getPixels();


    if (row_order == 0 || row_order == 1) {
        for (int y=0; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=0; x<width; x+=2) {
                one = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                b.putPixel(x,y,one);
                b.putPixel(x+1,y,one);
                b.putPixel(x,y+1,one);
                b.putPixel(x+1,y+1,one);
            }
        }

        for (int y=1; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=1; x<width; x+=2) {
                one = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                r.putPixel(x,y,one);
                r.putPixel(x+1,y,one);
                r.putPixel(x,y+1,one);
                r.putPixel(x+1,y+1,one);
            }
        }

        for (int y=0; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=1; x<width; x+=2) {
                one = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                g.putPixel(x,y,one);
                g.putPixel(x+1,y,one);
            }
        }   

        for (int y=1; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=0; x<width; x+=2) {
                one = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                g.putPixel(x,y,one);
                g.putPixel(x+1,y,one);
            }
        }   

        if (row_order == 0) {
            rgb.addSlice("red",b);  
            rgb.addSlice("green",g);
            rgb.addSlice("blue",r); 
        }
        else if (row_order == 1) {
            rgb.addSlice("red",r);  
            rgb.addSlice("green",g);
            rgb.addSlice("blue",b);         
        }
    }

    else if (row_order == 2 || row_order == 3) {
        for (int y=1; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=0; x<width; x+=2) {
                one = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                b.putPixel(x,y,one);
                b.putPixel(x+1,y,one);
                b.putPixel(x,y+1,one);
                b.putPixel(x+1,y+1,one);
            }
        }

        for (int y=0; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=1; x<width; x+=2) {
                one = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                r.putPixel(x,y,one);
                r.putPixel(x+1,y,one);
                r.putPixel(x,y+1,one);
                r.putPixel(x+1,y+1,one);
            }
        }

        for (int y=0; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=0; x<width; x+=2) {
                one = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                g.putPixel(x,y,one);
                g.putPixel(x+1,y,one);
            }
        }   

        for (int y=1; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=1; x<width; x+=2) {
                one = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                g.putPixel(x,y,one);
                g.putPixel(x+1,y,one);
            }
        }   

        if (row_order == 2) {
            rgb.addSlice("red",b);  
            rgb.addSlice("green",g);
            rgb.addSlice("blue",r); 
        }
        else if (row_order == 3) {
            rgb.addSlice("red",r);  
            rgb.addSlice("green",g);
            rgb.addSlice("blue",b);         
        }
    }

    return rgb;


}

ImageStack average_decode(int row_order) {          //Bilinear algorithm
    ip = imp.getProcessor();
    width = imp.getWidth();
    height = imp.getHeight();
    int one = 0;
    int two = 0;
    int three = 0;
    int four = 0;
    ImageStack rgb = new ImageStack(width, height, imp.getProcessor().getColorModel());
    ImageProcessor r = new ShortProcessor(width,height);
    ImageProcessor g = new ShortProcessor(width,height);
    ImageProcessor b = new ShortProcessor(width,height);
    //Short[] pixels = ip.getPixels();


    if (row_order == 0 || row_order == 1) {
        for (int y=0; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=0; x<width; x+=2) {
                one = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                two = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                three = ip.getPixel(x,y+2);
                four = ip.getPixel(x+2,y+2);

                b.putPixel(x,y,one);
                b.putPixel(x+1,y,(one+two)/2);
                b.putPixel(x,y+1,(one+three)/2);
                b.putPixel(x+1,y+1,(one+two+three+four)/4);
            }
        }

        for (int y=1; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=1; x<width; x+=2) {
                one = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                two = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                three = ip.getPixel(x,y+2);
                four = ip.getPixel(x+2,y+2);

                r.putPixel(x,y,one);
                r.putPixel(x+1,y,(one+two)/2);
                r.putPixel(x,y+1,(one+three)/2);
                r.putPixel(x+1,y+1,(one+two+three+four)/4);
            }
        }

        for (int y=0; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=1; x<width; x+=2) {
                one = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                two = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                three = ip.getPixel(x+1,y+1);
                four = ip.getPixel(x+1,y-1);

                g.putPixel(x,y,one);
                g.putPixel(x+1,y,(one+two+three+four)/4);
            }
        }   

        for (int y=1; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=0; x<width; x+=2) {
                one = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                two = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                three = ip.getPixel(x+1,y+1);
                four = ip.getPixel(x+1,y-1);

                g.putPixel(x,y,one);
                g.putPixel(x+1,y,(one+two+three+four)/4);
            }
        }   

        if (row_order == 0) {
            rgb.addSlice("red",b);  
            rgb.addSlice("green",g);
            rgb.addSlice("blue",r); 
        }
        else if (row_order == 1) {
            rgb.addSlice("red",r);  
            rgb.addSlice("green",g);
            rgb.addSlice("blue",b);         
        }
    }

    else if (row_order == 2 || row_order == 3) {
        for (int y=1; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=0; x<width; x+=2) {
                one = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                two = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                three = ip.getPixel(x,y+2);
                four = ip.getPixel(x+2,y+2);

                b.putPixel(x,y,one);
                b.putPixel(x+1,y,(one+two)/2);
                b.putPixel(x,y+1,(one+three)/2);
                b.putPixel(x+1,y+1,(one+two+three+four)/4);
            }
        }

        for (int y=0; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=1; x<width; x+=2) {
                one = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                two = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                three = ip.getPixel(x,y+2);
                four = ip.getPixel(x+2,y+2);

                r.putPixel(x,y,one);
                r.putPixel(x+1,y,(one+two)/2);
                r.putPixel(x,y+1,(one+three)/2);
                r.putPixel(x+1,y+1,(one+two+three+four)/4);             
            }
        }

        for (int y=0; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=0; x<width; x+=2) {
                one = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                two = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                three = ip.getPixel(x+1,y+1);
                four = ip.getPixel(x+1,y-1);

                g.putPixel(x,y,one);
                g.putPixel(x+1,y,(one+two+three+four)/4);
            }
        }   

        for (int y=1; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=1; x<width; x+=2) {
                one = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                two = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                three = ip.getPixel(x+1,y+1);
                four = ip.getPixel(x+1,y-1);

                g.putPixel(x,y,one);
                g.putPixel(x+1,y,(one+two+three+four)/4);
            }
        }   

        if (row_order == 2) {
            rgb.addSlice("red",b);  
            rgb.addSlice("green",g);
            rgb.addSlice("blue",r); 
        }
        else if (row_order == 3) {
            rgb.addSlice("red",r);  
            rgb.addSlice("green",g);
            rgb.addSlice("blue",b);         
        }
    }

    return rgb;


}

ImageStack smooth_decode(int row_order) {           //Smooth Hue algorithm
    ip = imp.getProcessor();
    width = imp.getWidth();
    height = imp.getHeight();
    double G1 = 0;
    double G2 = 0;
    double G3 = 0;
    double G4 = 0;
    double G5 = 0;
    double G6 = 0;
    double G7 = 0;
    double G8 = 0;
    double G9 = 0;
    double B1 = 0;
    double B2 = 0;
    double B3 = 0;
    double B4 = 0;
    double R1 = 0;
    double R2 = 0;
    double R3 = 0;
    double R4 = 0;
    ImageStack rgb = new ImageStack(width, height, imp.getProcessor().getColorModel());
    ImageProcessor r = new ShortProcessor(width,height);
    ImageProcessor g = new ShortProcessor(width,height);
    ImageProcessor b = new ShortProcessor(width,height);
    //Short[] pixels = ip.getPixels();


    if (row_order == 0 || row_order == 1) {
        //Solve for green pixels first
        for (int y=0; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=1; x<width; x+=2) {
                G1 = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                G2 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                G3 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y+1);
                G4 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y-1);

                g.putPixel(x,y,(int)G1);
                if (y==0) g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G1+G2+G3)/3));
                else g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G1+G2+G3+G4)/4));
                if (x==1) g.putPixel(x-1,y,(int)((G1+G4+ip.getPixel(x-1,y+1))/3));
            }
        }   

        for (int x=0; x<width; x+=2) {  
            for (int y=1; y<height; y+=2) {

                G1 = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                G2 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                G3 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y+1);
                G4 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y-1);

                g.putPixel(x,y,(int)G1);
                if (x==0) g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G1+G2+G3)/3));
                else g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G1+G2+G3+G4)/4));
            }
        }   

        g.putPixel(0,0,(int)((ip.getPixel(0,1)+ip.getPixel(1,0))/2));


        for (int y=0; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=0; x<width; x+=2) {
                B1 = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                B2 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                B3 = ip.getPixel(x,y+2);
                B4 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y+2);
                G1 = g.getPixel(x,y);
                G2 = g.getPixel(x+2,y);
                G3 = g.getPixel(x,y+2);
                G4 = g.getPixel(x+2,y+2);
                G5 = g.getPixel(x+1,y);
                G6 = g.getPixel(x,y+1);
                G9 = g.getPixel(x+1,y+1);
                if(G1==0) G1=1;
                if(G2==0) G2=1;
                if(G3==0) G3=1;
                if(G4==0) G4=1;

                b.putPixel(x,y,(int)(B1));
                b.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G5/2 * ((B1/G1) + (B2/G2)) )) );
                b.putPixel(x,y+1,(int)(( G6/2 * ((B1/G1) + (B3/G3)) )) );
                b.putPixel(x+1,y+1, (int)((G9/4 *  ((B1/G1) + (B3/G3) + (B2/G2) + (B4/G4)) )) );

            }
        }

        for (int y=1; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=1; x<width; x+=2) {
                R1 = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                R2 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                R3 = ip.getPixel(x,y+2);
                R4 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y+2);
                G1 = g.getPixel(x,y);
                G2 = g.getPixel(x+2,y);
                G3 = g.getPixel(x,y+2);
                G4 = g.getPixel(x+2,y+2);
                G5 = g.getPixel(x+1,y);
                G6 = g.getPixel(x,y+1);
                G9 = g.getPixel(x+1,y+1);
                if(G1==0) G1=1;
                if(G2==0) G2=1;
                if(G3==0) G3=1;
                if(G4==0) G4=1;

                r.putPixel(x,y,(int)(R1));
                r.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G5/2 * ((R1/G1) + (R2/G2) )) ));
                r.putPixel(x,y+1,(int)(( G6/2 * ((R1/G1) + (R3/G3) )) ));
                r.putPixel(x+1,y+1, (int)((G9/4 *  ((R1/G1) + (R3/G3) + (R2/G2) + (R4/G4)) ) ));
            }
        }


        if (row_order == 0) {
            rgb.addSlice("red",b);  
            rgb.addSlice("green",g);
            rgb.addSlice("blue",r); 
        }
        else if (row_order == 1) {
            rgb.addSlice("red",r);  
            rgb.addSlice("green",g);
            rgb.addSlice("blue",b);         
        }
    }

    else if (row_order == 2 || row_order == 3) {

        for (int y=0; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=0; x<width; x+=2) {
                G1 = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                G2 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                G3 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y+1);
                G4 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y-1);

                g.putPixel(x,y,(int)G1);
                if (y==0) g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G1+G2+G3)/3));
                else g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G1+G2+G3+G4)/4));
                if (x==1) g.putPixel(x-1,y,(int)((G1+G4+ip.getPixel(x-1,y+1))/3));
            }
        }   

        for (int y=1; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=1; x<width; x+=2) {
                G1 = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                G2 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                G3 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y+1);
                G4 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y-1);

                g.putPixel(x,y,(int)G1);
                if (x==0) g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G1+G2+G3)/3));
                else g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G1+G2+G3+G4)/4));
            }
        }

        g.putPixel(0,0,(int)((ip.getPixel(0,1)+ip.getPixel(1,0))/2));

        for (int y=1; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=0; x<width; x+=2) {
                B1 = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                B2 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                B3 = ip.getPixel(x,y+2);
                B4 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y+2);
                G1 = g.getPixel(x,y);
                G2 = g.getPixel(x+2,y);
                G3 = g.getPixel(x,y+2);
                G4 = g.getPixel(x+2,y+2);
                G5 = g.getPixel(x+1,y);
                G6 = g.getPixel(x,y+1);
                G9 = g.getPixel(x+1,y+1);
                if(G1==0) G1=1;
                if(G2==0) G2=1;
                if(G3==0) G3=1;
                if(G4==0) G4=1;

                b.putPixel(x,y,(int)(B1));
                b.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G5/2 * ((B1/G1) + (B2/G2)) )) );
                b.putPixel(x,y+1,(int)(( G6/2 * ((B1/G1) + (B3/G3)) )) );
                b.putPixel(x+1,y+1, (int)((G9/4 *  ((B1/G1) + (B3/G3) + (B2/G2) + (B4/G4)) )) );        

            }
        }

        for (int y=0; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=1; x<width; x+=2) {
                R1 = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                R2 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                R3 = ip.getPixel(x,y+2);
                R4 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y+2);
                G1 = g.getPixel(x,y);
                G2 = g.getPixel(x+2,y);
                G3 = g.getPixel(x,y+2);
                G4 = g.getPixel(x+2,y+2);
                G5 = g.getPixel(x+1,y);
                G6 = g.getPixel(x,y+1);
                G9 = g.getPixel(x+1,y+1);
                if(G1==0) G1=1;
                if(G2==0) G2=1;
                if(G3==0) G3=1;
                if(G4==0) G4=1;

                r.putPixel(x,y,(int)(R1));
                r.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G5/2 * ((R1/G1) + (R2/G2) )) ));
                r.putPixel(x,y+1,(int)(( G6/2 * ((R1/G1) + (R3/G3) )) ));
                r.putPixel(x+1,y+1, (int)((G9/4 *  ((R1/G1) + (R3/G3) + (R2/G2) + (R4/G4)) ) ));        
            }
        }



        if (row_order == 2) {
            rgb.addSlice("red",b);  
            rgb.addSlice("green",g);
            rgb.addSlice("blue",r); 
        }
        else if (row_order == 3) {
            rgb.addSlice("red",r);  
            rgb.addSlice("green",g);
            rgb.addSlice("blue",b);         
        }
    }

    return rgb;


}

ImageStack adaptive_decode(int row_order) {         //Adaptive Smooth Hue algorithm (Edge detecting)
    ip = imp.getProcessor();
    width = imp.getWidth();
    height = imp.getHeight();
    double G1 = 0;
    double G2 = 0;
    double G3 = 0;
    double G4 = 0;
    double G5 = 0;
    double G6 = 0;
    double G7 = 0;
    double G8 = 0;
    double G9 = 0;
    double B1 = 0;
    double B2 = 0;
    double B3 = 0;
    double B4 = 0;
    double B5 = 0;
    double R1 = 0;
    double R2 = 0;
    double R3 = 0;
    double R4 = 0;
    double R5 = 0;
    double N = 0;
    double S = 0;
    double E = 0;
    double W = 0;
    ImageStack rgb = new ImageStack(width, height, imp.getProcessor().getColorModel());
    ImageProcessor r = new ShortProcessor(width,height);
    ImageProcessor g = new ShortProcessor(width,height);
    ImageProcessor b = new ShortProcessor(width,height);
    //Short[] pixels = ip.getPixels();


    if (row_order == 0 || row_order == 1) {
        //Solve for green pixels first
        for (int y=0; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=1; x<width; x+=2) {
                G1 = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                G2 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                G3 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y+1);
                G4 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y-1);
                R1 = ip.getPixel(x-1,y);
                R2 = ip.getPixel(x+3,y);
                R3 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y+2);
                R4 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y-2);
                R5 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y+1);

                N = Math.abs(R4-R5)*2 + Math.abs(G4-G3);
                S = Math.abs(R5-R3)*2 + Math.abs(G4-G3);
                E = Math.abs(R5-R2)*2 + Math.abs(G1-G2);
                W = Math.abs(R1-R5)*2 + Math.abs(G1-G2);

                if(N<S && N<E && N<W) {
                    g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G4*3 + R5 + G3 - R4)/4));
                }

                else if(S<N && S<E && S<W) {
                    g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G3*3 + R5 + G4 - R3)/4));
                }

                else if(W<N && W<E && W<S) {
                    g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G1*3 + R5 + G2 - R1)/4));
                }

                else if(E<N && E<S && E<W) {
                    g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G2*3 + R5 + G1 - R2)/4));
                }

                g.putPixel(x,y,(int)G1);

                if (y==0) g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G1+G2+G3)/3));
                else g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G1+G2+G3+G4)/4));
                if (x==1) g.putPixel(x-1,y,(int)((G1+G4+ip.getPixel(x-1,y+1))/3));
            }
        }   

        for (int x=0; x<width; x+=2) {  
            for (int y=1; y<height; y+=2) {
                G1 = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                G2 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                G3 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y+1);
                G4 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y-1);
                R1 = ip.getPixel(x-1,y);
                R2 = ip.getPixel(x+3,y);
                R3 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y+2);
                R4 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y-2);
                R5 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y+1);

                N = Math.abs(R4-R5)*2 + Math.abs(G4-G3);
                S = Math.abs(R5-R3)*2 + Math.abs(G4-G3);
                E = Math.abs(R5-R2)*2 + Math.abs(G1-G2);
                W = Math.abs(R1-R5)*2 + Math.abs(G1-G2);

                if(N<S && N<E && N<W) {
                    g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G4*3 + R5 + G3 - R4)/4));
                }

                else if(S<N && S<E && S<W) {
                    g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G3*3 + R5 + G4 - R3)/4));
                }

                else if(W<N && W<E && W<S) {
                    g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G1*3 + R5 + G2 - R1)/4));
                }

                else if(E<N && E<S && E<W) {
                    g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G2*3 + R5 + G1 - R2)/4));
                }

                g.putPixel(x,y,(int)G1);
                if (x==0) g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G1+G2+G3)/3));
                else g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G1+G2+G3+G4)/4));
            }
        }   

        g.putPixel(0,0,(int)((ip.getPixel(0,1)+ip.getPixel(1,0))/2));


        for (int y=0; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=0; x<width; x+=2) {
                B1 = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                B2 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                B3 = ip.getPixel(x,y+2);
                B4 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y+2);
                G1 = g.getPixel(x,y);
                G2 = g.getPixel(x+2,y);
                G3 = g.getPixel(x,y+2);
                G4 = g.getPixel(x+2,y+2);
                G5 = g.getPixel(x+1,y);
                G6 = g.getPixel(x,y+1);
                G9 = g.getPixel(x+1,y+1);
                if(G1==0) G1=1;
                if(G2==0) G2=1;
                if(G3==0) G3=1;
                if(G4==0) G4=1;

                b.putPixel(x,y,(int)(B1));
                b.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G5/2 * ((B1/G1) + (B2/G2)) )) );
                b.putPixel(x,y+1,(int)(( G6/2 * ((B1/G1) + (B3/G3)) )) );
                b.putPixel(x+1,y+1, (int)((G9/4 *  ((B1/G1) + (B3/G3) + (B2/G2) + (B4/G4)) )) );

            }
        }

        for (int y=1; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=1; x<width; x+=2) {
                R1 = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                R2 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                R3 = ip.getPixel(x,y+2);
                R4 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y+2);
                G1 = g.getPixel(x,y);
                G2 = g.getPixel(x+2,y);
                G3 = g.getPixel(x,y+2);
                G4 = g.getPixel(x+2,y+2);
                G5 = g.getPixel(x+1,y);
                G6 = g.getPixel(x,y+1);
                G9 = g.getPixel(x+1,y+1);
                if(G1==0) G1=1;
                if(G2==0) G2=1;
                if(G3==0) G3=1;
                if(G4==0) G4=1;

                r.putPixel(x,y,(int)(R1));
                r.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G5/2 * ((R1/G1) + (R2/G2) )) ));
                r.putPixel(x,y+1,(int)(( G6/2 * ((R1/G1) + (R3/G3) )) ));
                r.putPixel(x+1,y+1, (int)((G9/4 *  ((R1/G1) + (R3/G3) + (R2/G2) + (R4/G4)) ) ));
            }
        }


        if (row_order == 0) {
            rgb.addSlice("red",b);  
            rgb.addSlice("green",g);
            rgb.addSlice("blue",r); 
        }
        else if (row_order == 1) {
            rgb.addSlice("red",r);  
            rgb.addSlice("green",g);
            rgb.addSlice("blue",b);         
        }
    }

    else if (row_order == 2 || row_order == 3) {

        for (int y=0; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=0; x<width; x+=2) {
                G1 = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                G2 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                G3 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y+1);
                G4 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y-1);
                R1 = ip.getPixel(x-1,y);
                R2 = ip.getPixel(x+3,y);
                R3 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y+2);
                R4 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y-2);
                R5 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y+1);

                N = Math.abs(R4-R5)*2 + Math.abs(G4-G3);
                S = Math.abs(R5-R3)*2 + Math.abs(G4-G3);
                E = Math.abs(R5-R2)*2 + Math.abs(G1-G2);
                W = Math.abs(R1-R5)*2 + Math.abs(G1-G2);

                if(N<S && N<E && N<W) {
                    g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G4*3 + R5 + G3 - R4)/4));
                }

                else if(S<N && S<E && S<W) {
                    g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G3*3 + R5 + G4 - R3)/4));
                }

                else if(W<N && W<E && W<S) {
                    g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G1*3 + R5 + G2 - R1)/4));
                }

                else if(E<N && E<S && E<W) {
                    g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G2*3 + R5 + G1 - R2)/4));
                }

                g.putPixel(x,y,(int)G1);
                if (y==0) g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G1+G2+G3)/3));
                else g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G1+G2+G3+G4)/4));
                if (x==1) g.putPixel(x-1,y,(int)((G1+G4+ip.getPixel(x-1,y+1))/3));
            }
        }   

        for (int y=1; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=1; x<width; x+=2) {
                G1 = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                G2 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                G3 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y+1);
                G4 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y-1);
                R1 = ip.getPixel(x-1,y);
                R2 = ip.getPixel(x+3,y);
                R3 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y+2);
                R4 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y-2);
                R5 = ip.getPixel(x+1,y+1);

                N = Math.abs(R4-R5)*2 + Math.abs(G4-G3);
                S = Math.abs(R5-R3)*2 + Math.abs(G4-G3);
                E = Math.abs(R5-R2)*2 + Math.abs(G1-G2);
                W = Math.abs(R1-R5)*2 + Math.abs(G1-G2);

                if(N<S && N<E && N<W) {
                    g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G4*3 + R5 + G3 - R4)/4));
                }

                else if(S<N && S<E && S<W) {
                    g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G3*3 + R5 + G4 - R3)/4));
                }

                else if(W<N && W<E && W<S) {
                    g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G1*3 + R5 + G2 - R1)/4));
                }

                else if(E<N && E<S && E<W) {
                    g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G2*3 + R5 + G1 - R2)/4));
                }

                g.putPixel(x,y,(int)G1);
                if (x==0) g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G1+G2+G3)/3));
                else g.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G1+G2+G3+G4)/4));
            }
        }

        g.putPixel(0,0,(int)((ip.getPixel(0,1)+ip.getPixel(1,0))/2));

        for (int y=1; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=0; x<width; x+=2) {
                B1 = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                B2 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                B3 = ip.getPixel(x,y+2);
                B4 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y+2);
                G1 = g.getPixel(x,y);
                G2 = g.getPixel(x+2,y);
                G3 = g.getPixel(x,y+2);
                G4 = g.getPixel(x+2,y+2);
                G5 = g.getPixel(x+1,y);
                G6 = g.getPixel(x,y+1);
                G9 = g.getPixel(x+1,y+1);
                if(G1==0) G1=1;
                if(G2==0) G2=1;
                if(G3==0) G3=1;
                if(G4==0) G4=1;

                b.putPixel(x,y,(int)(B1));
                b.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G5/2 * ((B1/G1) + (B2/G2)) )) );
                b.putPixel(x,y+1,(int)(( G6/2 * ((B1/G1) + (B3/G3)) )) );
                b.putPixel(x+1,y+1, (int)((G9/4 *  ((B1/G1) + (B3/G3) + (B2/G2) + (B4/G4)) )) );        

            }
        }

        for (int y=0; y<height; y+=2) {
            for (int x=1; x<width; x+=2) {
                R1 = ip.getPixel(x,y);
                R2 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y);
                R3 = ip.getPixel(x,y+2);
                R4 = ip.getPixel(x+2,y+2);
                G1 = g.getPixel(x,y);
                G2 = g.getPixel(x+2,y);
                G3 = g.getPixel(x,y+2);
                G4 = g.getPixel(x+2,y+2);
                G5 = g.getPixel(x+1,y);
                G6 = g.getPixel(x,y+1);
                G9 = g.getPixel(x+1,y+1);
                if(G1==0) G1=1;
                if(G2==0) G2=1;
                if(G3==0) G3=1;
                if(G4==0) G4=1;

                r.putPixel(x,y,(int)(R1));
                r.putPixel(x+1,y,(int)((G5/2 * ((R1/G1) + (R2/G2) )) ));
                r.putPixel(x,y+1,(int)(( G6/2 * ((R1/G1) + (R3/G3) )) ));
                r.putPixel(x+1,y+1, (int)((G9/4 *  ((R1/G1) + (R3/G3) + (R2/G2) + (R4/G4)) ) ));        
            }
        }



        if (row_order == 2) {
            rgb.addSlice("red",b);  
            rgb.addSlice("green",g);
            rgb.addSlice("blue",r); 
        }
        else if (row_order == 3) {
            rgb.addSlice("red",r);  
            rgb.addSlice("green",g);
            rgb.addSlice("blue",b);         
        }
    }

    return rgb;


}
```

<sup>Based on scripts by [PHYS 2070](http://umanitoba.ca/faculties/science/astronomy/jwest/plugins.html)</sup>